# A regular expression to match the server root

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match the next pattern : `\server\root\`
So if the path is longer such as `\\server\root\subroot` it is not matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the required pattern occurs at the start of the string, *and* at the end of the string (i.e. nothing follows it).

```
^\\server\\root\\$
```

You will most likely have to escape the slashes, hence the double `\\`.

If the requirement is to match *any* two-level path ,the following might be useful

```
^\\[\w]+\\[\w]+\\$
```

Comment: Change the pattern to whatever your server root is. Or are you saying you simply want to match any two-level path?

Comment: valid characters for directory names include more then [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: Yup. That's why I said _might_. I don't know the OPs dir name requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
\server\root\$
```

above should do it, it says it must end with a root. and it will not match anything else.

Comment: you may want to add some escaping and add a start of string

Comment: my answer was not language specific. if u use this regex in apache .htacces it will work without escaping. but if u intend to use in say java, u need to escape. 

^ is required at the start of the string, if its reuquired. ( i thought the question was not specific enough)

Answer (score 0):

`^\\[\w]+\\[\w]+\\$` should match any two level paths.

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
^\\[[:word:]]+\\[[:word:]]+\\$
```

will be OK. You can replace `[[:word:]]` with `\w` probably, depending on your regex engine.